# How to create a route in Gmap.net wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I hope you can help me. I can not find anything helpful in the web for the WPF version of GMap.net.

Problem: I don't see my route.

```
List<Location> points = PolylinePoint.Decode(responseData.routes.First().overview_polyline.points);

GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapRoute route = new GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapRoute(points.Select(x => new PointLatLng(x.Latitude.Value, x.Longitude.Value)));
route.ZIndex = ROUTESLIST;
route.Shape = new Line() { StrokeThickness = 4, Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.BlueViolet };
this.routenList.Clear();
this.routenList.Add(route);
```

The main problem is, that I can not use an overlay like in the GMap.NET tutorials.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The [project site](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) does have quite a few samples, also for routes in WPF.

Comment: In order to provide additional help, please provide more of the work you've done, especially let us know what `routenlist` and `ROUTESLIST` stand for.

Answer (score 3):

```
    RoutingProvider routingProvider = 
       _map.MapProvider as RoutingProvider ?? GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;

    MapRoute route = routingProvider.GetRoute(
        new PointLatLng(35.834914, -76.009508), //start
        new PointLatLng(35.854914, -76.009508), //end
        false, //avoid highways 
        false, //walking mode
        (int)_map.Zoom);

    GMapRoute gmRoute = new GMapRoute(route.Points);

    _map.Markers.Add(gmRoute);
```

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to add a marker and add the route points to the `Route` of the marker:

```
var track = new List<PointLatLng>();

// add PointLatLngs to 'track' here

var routeMarker = new GMapMarker(track.First());
routeMarker.Route.AddRange(track);

// don't forget to add the marker to the map
_mapControl.Markers.Add(routeMarker);
```

Comment: Where does the `Route` property come from?