# I can not Add route to GmapControl

Tags: c#, wpf, overlay, gmap.net

My project is WPF.
using these part of code I am trying to add route:

```
PointLatLng start = new PointLatLng(34.633440, 50.867821);
PointLatLng end = new PointLatLng(34.618707, 50.844945);
MapRoute route = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(
start, end, false, false, 15);
```

But in all articles they say I must add the created route to an overlay. And then add the overlays to my Control. But there is no overlay to add.
How can I add the route to my Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there is no overlay to add

<del>In your code snippets, the MapRoute instance has been created. We'll need to do the following things:</del>

<del>1. Wrap the route up in a GMapRoute instance, the GMapRoute constructor
    takes a set of points.</del>

<del>2. Added GMapRoute instance to an overlay</del>

<del>3. Add overlay to GMapControl</del>

<del>**Reference:** [ADDING THE ROUTE TO THE MAP](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-routes/)</del>

**--------Update 5/11/2016--------**

For WPF application, we have to wrap the route up in a **GMapRoute** instance and add into **GMapControl.Markers**:

```
 RoutingProvider rp = gmap1.MapProvider as RoutingProvider;
 if (rp == null)
 {
            rp = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap; // use OpenStreetMap if provider does not implement routing
 }

 MapRoute route = rp.GetRoute(start, end, false, false, 15);

 if (route != null)
 {
            GMapRoute mRoute = new GMapRoute(route.Points);
            {
                mRoute.ZIndex = -1;
            }

            gmap1.Markers.Add(mRoute);

            gmap1.ZoomAndCenterMarkers(null);
 }
 else
 {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There is no route");
 }
```

**I created a sample for you, please check [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/WPF-Samples/tree/master/GMapWpfApplication1)**

Comment: Are you kidding me? You think I didn't find that reference? I am telling you the Overlay object does not known in my wpf project

Comment: @MeysamTolouee Okay, I have updated my answer with a completed sample, the first document is for traditional Winform project, so please use Markers instead

Comment: A bit of an more abbreviated existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35500767

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT 'GMapRoute' does not known in my project as type.

Comment: @MeysamTolouee Have you checked my github demo? What's your nuget package version?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT I have no NUget package

Comment: @MeysamTolouee What's your visual studio version? You can use Nuget package manager to add package in VS2013+

Comment: @MeysamTolouee If you add reference directly, don't forget to append namespace

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT It is 2015. How Nuget package works? I never used Nuget.

Comment: @MeysamTolouee There are lots of documents about using Nuget package manager in VS2015 on the internet, it's simple and clear to manage packages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112178/discussion-between-meysam-tolouee-and-franklin-chen-msft).